# Can't turn any features on or off in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation

I'm running Windows 10 Pro on a Lenovo X1 Extreme Gen 2.

Whenever I try to turn any feature on or off in "Turn Windows features on or off," I get the following error message: An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed.

I tried installing Hyper-V. I tried installing IIS. I tried installing Windows Process Activation Service.

I checked the Event Viewer and couldn't find anything relevant.

What could be going on? SFC /scannow didn't find any corrupt files.

I searched on Bing and couldn't find any satisfactory solution.

Comment: The Windows Process Activation service is built into Windows if it’s not installed that means your running an inactivated copy of Windows.  Reinstall Windows and use a license key

Comment: Shouldn't there be a notification that Windows is not activated?

Comment: That is handled by WSA which is not running.

Comment: Fair enough. I successfully enabled Windows Process Activation Service.

Comment: WPA not WSA; My suggestion stands. Reinstall Windows and activate it with a legitimate license code. There are only a couple reasons the WPA would not be running and the majority of those reasons are linked to using methods to purposefully disable it.

Comment: I checked to see if Windows is activated and it says "Windows is activated with a digital license linked to your Microsoft account"

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever I try to turn any feature on or off in "Turn Windows features
> on or off," I get the following error message: An error has occurred.
> Not all of the features were successfully changed.
>
> What could be going on? SFC /scannow didn't find any corrupt files.

First run DISM and Restart and Test.

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test

Then if that does not work, run a Windows 10 Repair Install

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with Keep Everything. Hopefully that will work as repairs get more aggressive if not.